# Debugging Galaxy S2 Bluetooth problem: Bluetooth disconnects, Bluetooth status never fully turns on, Only reboot resolves this

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth, logging

I know many have problems with Bluetooth and certain car kits. I specifically have a VW. In any case, my Galaxy disconnects from not only my car, but also from my Philips in home audio system. In both cases, the disconnect is the same. What happens in both cases is the Bluetooth pair is lost. If I try to turn off and then on the Bluetooth (on the phone) to reset the pair the Bluetooth light never fully turns on. It stays a dim green. To get it to work I have to restart the phone.

I wrote a script to collect the Bluetooth logs, and programmed it to start logging whenever Buetooth is connected. See link below for the3 log. notice that around 7:56 the probem occurred. I was in a call on my galaxy s2 connected to my vw tiguan, and the hands free audio stopped. I was able to pick up the phone and switch from hands free to the speaker (on the phone) to resume the call.

Around 8:19, I think, I turned off the Bluetooth on the phone, and then tried to to turn on it again. But,it did not fully turn on. The green Bluetooth light is dim rather then bright. The only way I can restart the Bluetooth is to reboot the phone.

There are exceptions thrown that I am going to look at.

Have any thoughts?

Thanks!

I am running the stock rom that I downloaded from Kies. The Android version is 4.1.2

Logs:
1. S2 paired with VW Tiguan (7:56, 8:19 approx)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd809geb4hoxvrr/btlog.txt


2. S2 paired with Philips AS351 (Time 21:02-21:06 approx)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6w7je0xrdcn7kiy/20130916_902-906btlog.txt

Comment: Did you consider giving Cyanogenmod a try? I think this would be your best bet, because debugging could become time intensive and costly, and maybe turn out that it's something you can't fix yourself (e.g. because low lever firmware related). I think that's you best bet.

Comment: I have used Cyan, but have found the interface on the stock samsung rom is much better.  It has been a while tho, and perhaps they have fixed this in later versions of Cyanogen.  However, the last time I tried it the problem was there too. I will give it another shot tho.  I don't mind the debugging, but you are right as far as it possibly being a waste of time.

Comment: In particular if the problem also appear with a different ROM. That would rule out most software components and only leave the firmware/hardware as possible error causes. I am not a friend of Samsungs TouchWiz and really enjoy the plain CM interface. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have also been using Bluetooth Keepalive from Google Play.  Not sure if it is helping just yet.  One thing about debugging this that is very difficult is that I am not sure how to recreate the issue.  So, I just have to wait for it to appear and catch it in the log

Comment: Hi, I tried CM 10.1, and the problem was horrible!  Happened a lot.  I am currently testing with CM 10.2 which might be better.  I will stick with whatever works, but I also forgot about the echo problem in CM.  That is the main reason I discontinued using.  I have noise suppression on, and the echo is still there. But that is another issue for me to look at. haha.  Will let you know what I find out.  Thx.

Comment: Here is where I am.. I have spent quite a bit of time over the past few weeks testing different Android versions, testing Bluetooth Keepalive, speaking to other developers, logging errors and debugging, installing different versions of Cyanogenmod, and speaking to Samsung.

In short here is what I have found:

1. The problem still exists in the stock rom that is downloaded from Kies with Android version 4.1.2.
2. Problem was still encountered, and potentially worse, on Cyanogenmod 10.1 with Android 4.2. (Problem happened more frequently)

Comment: Continued.. 3. Still testing with Cyanogenmod 10.2 with Android 4.3, and so far I have NOT had any issue.
4. I have had mixed results with Bluetooth Keepalive, but have been in contact with the developer.

I spoke with Samsung yesterday as well as last month. I requested a call from a developer, but they would not allow.  They said they would connect me to the next level of support, but I would have to wait on hold for an hour.  Oddly enough, I did not want to or have time to wait an hour.

Comment: Continued.. However, over the coming days I am going to contact Samsung using a more direct method in hopes of speaking to a developer.  The tech guy I talked to seemed to indicate that it was his position that it was a 3rd party issue, and I should contact my auto manufacturer.  I explained to him that this problem happens across multiple auto manufacturers, and the one common theme is the Galaxy phone.  In addition, my auto manufacturer has replaced everything Bluetooth related, and has had no issue testing with other phone models.

Comment: Continued.. The Samsung rep  also said, and I agree, that sending the phone into Samsung for repair would be worthless.  

Short of rooting your phone and installing CM 10.2 with Android 4.3 the problem still exists. Again, I am still testing with CM 10.2, and look forward to speaking with Samsung again.