# How can I decode the Bluetooth Error numbers found in errno, that show up in Android log?

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to find the definition of the Bluetooth Error Numbers.  For example they might appear in logcat output as:

> 09-16 07:38:50.896 V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 8809): ...accept(69, RFCOMM)
>   = -1 (errno 125)

Answer (score 2):

The `errno` global variable concept is not Bluetooth specific but comes from the (POSIX) system calls used by `BluetoothSocket.cpp`. Your log shows that the system call `accept()` failed, because it returned `-1` (negative values usually indicate an error). Additionally `accept()` also set the `errno` to 125. If you look at the [related definition in the Linux sources](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc1), you find that it maps to ECANCELED:

```
#define ECANCELED   125 /* Operation Canceled */
```

See also

- [Wikipedia on errno.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)
- [POSIX errno.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information.  Perhaps you might have an idea about my other related question regarding Bluetooth. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53477/debugging-galaxy-s2-bluetooth-problem